# if both the selection sort and bubble sort algorithms have a cost of O(N2) then why is this not reflected in my code?

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort, selection-sort

in my program i am attempting to compare the bubble sort and selection sort algorithms, however when comparing the results bubble sort takes about 10 seconds to sort a randomised array of 10000 and selection sort takes 2.

i have compared my code to the code of peers and it does not seem to be caused by the function itself, although i havent ruled it out.

the full program is linked here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sfOZN_lLBeSmtZJpzmpVjCr5JOeHD9V0/view?usp=sharing

i expect the output to be a bit higher than selection sort but instead it is much higher.

Comment: Big-O is a measure of how the algorithm *scales* with respect to input size. Test each algorithm with a range of different input sizes, and graph their execution times. You'll see two graphs that look somewhat like `y = mx^2 + c` with different values of `m` and `c`.

Answer (score 2):

Big O notation is not equivalant to time. It is a measure of time complexity. Take the following snippets as examples:

Snippet A:

```py
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(n):
      # operation
```

Snippet B:

```py
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(n):
      # operation
   for k in range(n):
      # operation
   for q in range(n):
      # operation
```

Snippet C:

```py
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(n):
      # operation
   for k in range(n):
      # operation
for q in range(100):
   # operation
```

In snippet A, the operation would be run `N^2` times, in the snippet B, the operation would be run `3N^2` times and in the last snippet it would run `2N^2+100` times; however, considering operation has `O(1)`, all three snippets would have time complexity of `O(N^2)` but it's obvious that running them would not take equal time.

Take a look at this informative [video](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/algorithms-divide-conquer/big-oh-notation-KGtUp) for more information.